# Wrapping GWT DialogBox footer

Tags: gwt

DialogBox is in fact set of `<div>` elements. There is basically TitleBar, MainContent and the Footer. By default adding elements to DialogBox will throw them into main Content.

What I want is to throw something into footer. Its basically this div:  `<div class="dialogBottomCenterInner">`

I made this method inside the class that inherits from DialogBox to wrap the footer:

```
public HTMLPanel getFooter() {
    Element td = getCellElement(2, 1);
    td.setId("footer"); //html at this point = <div class="dialogBottomCenterInner" id="footer"></div>              
    HTMLPanel panel = HTMLPanel.wrap(td);
    return panel;
}
```

Unfortunatelly it fails at `HTMLPanel.wrap(td);`with 
java.lang.AssertionError: null

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the div to the footer of the dialog? Is it just to place it at the bottom of the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

There is no footer in a DialogBox. The element you refer to is a part of a border that surrounds the DialogBox.